# MongoDB is always saving 03:00:00 as time for a DateTime property

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Considering I have the following code:

```
public class Project
{
   ...

   public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

   ...
}

var project = new Project();
project.CreationDate = new DateTime(2020, 2, 3); // Setting 03/02/2020 date

await _mongoDbContext.Projects.InsertOneAsync(project);
```

After inserting the document, when I get it back, the `CreationDate` property has the **03/02/2020 03:00:00** value instead of **03/02/2020 00:00:00**.

**Edit**

That's the way I get the projects back (ProjectTypes is an Enum):

```
var filter = Builders<Project>.Filter.Eq(x => x.ProjectType, (int)ProjectTypes.Activity);
var projects = _mongoDbContext.Projects.Find(filter).ToList();
```

**Potential answer**

It looks like using `[BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Local)]` annotation works for this problem.

```
public class Project
{
   ...

   [BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Local)]
   public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

   ...
}
```

As the @Prasad and @Kit have suggested.

Comment: May be it is saving as a UTC time? What is your time zone?

Comment: How do you get it back? Can you update your question with that part of code as well?

Comment: I have edited my question by explaining how I get the projects back. I'm from Brazil (GMT -3:00).

Comment: Try specifying the `DateTime.Kind` property.

Answer (score 1):

this is happening because the driver is converting DateTimes to UTC before storage in the db. see the source code [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Bson/Serialization/Serializers/DateTimeSerializer.cs#L281)

it is best practise to always deal with UTC in your app code and then convert it to local time on presentation of the data to the end user.

for example at record creation you do this:

```cs
    CreationDate = new DateTime(2020, 02, 03)

    //this is not neccessary as the driver takes care of the conversion
    CreationDate = new DateTime(2020, 02, 03, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)
```

and on presentation you do this:

```cs
    project.CreationDate.ToLocalTime()
```

if your presentation layer is some js framework, you send the data down to the web app in utc and javscript converts it to the user's local time upon display.

the reason to deal with UTC only in app code is because even if your code runs on multiple computers in multiple geographies in the future, your code is only concerned with a single timezone. convertion to local time is a responsibility of the presentation logic.

Comment: Thank you for replying @Ryan!